# UICollectionViewController with embedded search bar controller in Navigation bar

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, xcode9, uisearchcontroller

I've embedded a `UISearchController` into a `NavigationBar` of a  `UICollectionViewController`
The code for search bar controller is

```
extension SearchCollectionViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        getSearchResult(query: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}

class SearchCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.isActive = true
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }
}
```

When number of collection view items are as many as fill out the whole view  (e.g. more than 30 items in `CollectionView`) I am able to pull down the `CollectionView` and the `SearchBar` will appear.

[image: Search bar is showing]

But when the items are not filling out the whole page (e.g. only 10 items in the `CollectionView`) there is no way to present the search bar. I'm not able to pull down the `CollectionView`, so no `SearchBar` appears!

[image: Search bar is not showing]

How can I make the `CollectionView` be able to be pulled down even when the number of items are not filling the whole view?

Comment: This is native behavior of the system as search bar isn't required for that small number of cells because all cells are visible. Why you want searchbar in this case ? if your collectionview will have large number of cells then searchbar will definitely visible.

Comment: @Lion Because the search bar will search through some properties of items which are not visible oh the presentations of them  in `CollectionView`. So the search functionality would be a nice feature

Comment: navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false has worked for me